# GitLab on GKE: Configure Mailserver

Tags: email, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, sendgrid

I'm trying to set up a GitLab-Server on GKE (from marketplace). As a part of this I want to configure mail-functionality. I created a Sendgrid-Account and found the following [manual](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html).

But now I'm confused: Where can I find the mentioned config file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`? The installation from marketplace created the following pods:

```
gitlab-1-deployer
gitlab-1-gitaly
gitlab-1-gitlab-shell
gitlab-1-migrations
gitlab-1-minio
gitlab-1-minio-create-buckets
gitlab-1-nginx-ingress-controller
gitlab-1-nginx-ingress-default-backend
gitlab-1-postgresql
gitlab-1-redis
gitlab-1-registry
gitlab-1-shared-secrets
gitlab-1-sidekiq-all-in
gitlab-1-task-runner
gitlab-1-unicorn
```

Do I need to connect to one of this pods by console and edit the config-file? And if yes, to which of them?

Thanks in advance!